# ConTeXt: Squiggly Underbar

Tags: formatting, context, text-decorations

Is it possible to create a squiggly underline? Like this, but wavy:

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\starttext
\underbar{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

Comment: If ConTeXt can use the `ulem` package, it defines the `\uwave{something}` command.

Comment: @TeXnician link?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't think `\definehighlight` is the right mechanism.  I would suggest `undergraphic` instead (see my answer).

Comment: @HenriMenke Much better. I'm still learning about all these options as well ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily define your own [`undergraphic`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/979450762f4ef3b885fd63984c91165726494564/tex/context/base/mkiv/node-rul.mkiv#L288-L343) with a sine wave in MetaFun.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\startuseMPgraphic{rules:under:wave}
    draw function(2, "x", "sin(2*(x mod (2*pi)))", 0, RuleWidth, 1pt)
        shifted (0,RuleFactor*RuleOffset+RuleDepth)
        withpen pencircle scaled RuleThickness
        withcolor RuleColor ;
    setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xysized(RuleWidth,RuleHeight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definebar
  [underwave]
  [undergraphic]
  [mp=rules:under:wave]

\definebar
  [underwaves]
  [underwave]
  [continue=yes]

\starttext
\underwaves{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

A method to avoid overflow could be to use hand-drawn waves.  It looks a bit awkward right now.  There is definitely room for improvement.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\startuseMPgraphic{rules:under:wave}
  numeric n ; n := 2 ;
  path p ;
  p := (0,RuleDepth) for i=0 step n until RuleWidth:
      .. (i,RuleDepth) .. (i+1*n/4,RuleDepth+1pt) .. (i+2*n/4,RuleDepth) .. (i+3*n/4,RuleDepth-1pt)
  endfor ;
  draw p shifted (0,RuleFactor*RuleOffset)
        withpen pencircle scaled RuleThickness
        withcolor RuleColor ;
    setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xysized(RuleWidth,RuleHeight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definebar
  [underwave]
  [undergraphic]
  [mp=rules:under:wave]

\definebar
  [underwaves]
  [underwave]
  [continue=yes]

\starttext
\underwaves{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

Another option to avoid overflow is to compute the sine in Lua.

```
\setupwhitespace[big]

\startuseMPgraphic{rules:under:wave}
    vardef lsin primary x =
        lua("mp.print(math.sin(" & decimal x & "))")
    enddef ;
    draw function(1, "x", "lsin(2*x)", 0, RuleWidth, .2pt)
        shifted (0,RuleFactor*RuleOffset+RuleDepth)
        withpen pencircle scaled RuleThickness
        withcolor RuleColor ;
    setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare xysized(RuleWidth,RuleHeight) ;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definebar
  [underwave]
  [undergraphic]
  [mp=rules:under:wave]

\definebar
  [underwaves]
  [underwave]
  [continue=yes]

\starttext
\underwaves{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't think it'd be so easy. Appreciate for the link to `undergraphic`. There's also the [Rules PDF](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/rules-mkiv.pdf) (just found it), and of course [MetaFun](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf). Quick question: how do I squish the squiggles together? Scaling the first x (`x/2`) or using `xyscaled (0.5,1)` truncates the graphic to half the line length, and scaling the second x (`sin(x*2)`) causes an out-of-bounds metapost error.

Comment: @user19087 You have to use some arithmetic tricks to avoid overflows.  See updated answer.

Comment: Heh you're right, if I use `\setuppapersize[A2]` the original `sin(x)` overflows. And here I assumed the overflow was a `sin` result so small the exponent overflowed & wrapped to produce a value beyond `[-1,1]`. You have to increase the step (`0.25pt`) to keep the curve from appearing drunk, as though it was drawn using method `function(1, ...)`.

Comment: @user19087 You could just use hand-drawn waves to avoid any overflow.  MetaPost is not very good with numbers.  See updated answer.

Comment: @user19087 Or you could even escape to Lua and compute the sine there.

Comment: Instead of escaping to Lua, another option is to use the `doublefun` instance to get more accuracy.

Comment: @Aditya I was thinking about that too but couldn't find out how to switch the instance for a single graphic (or even thr global instance).

Comment: I cannot test now, but simply adding `doublefun::` before the name of the MP graphic should work. See the visualcounter module as an example of how to use MP instances.

Comment: @Aditya Just adding `doublefun::` doesn't suffice (https://termbin.com/88wt) and neither does `decimalfun::` etc.

Comment: Looking at the definitions in `node-rul.lua`, I am not sure how to call a MP graphic from a different instance. We should ask Hans on the mailing list.